# How do I use a variable in an input mask in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a field in a database for which the input mask should change based on a global variable that I have set elsewhere. How do I set the input mask ensuring that all its characters before the user input (including the variable) are taken as literal?

I've tried this:

```
Me.txtSomeControl.InputMask = varMyVariable & "00000;;*"
```

But when it comes to runtime, any characters in the variable that are special inputmask characters are taken as special, not literal. Ie if varMyVariable was LLL it would require those characters to be a letter or digit entered, rather than what I intend, which is just LLL in the input mask.

Would I have to split the variable into separate characters and escape each of them or is there an easier way?

Comment: Just make the input mask work in your textbox without any variable and then copy the section you want and store it in your variable. Any time you use a special character as a literal you need to put a \ character before the special character so that Access knows it's a literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Me.txtSomeControl.InputMask = Chr(34) & varMyVariable & Chr(34) & "00000;;*"
```

You need to put double quotes around any literals in your input mask.  The easiest way to do that (IMHO) is to use chr(34) which is the double quote character.  So:

```
varMyVariable = "LLL"
Me.txtSomeControl.InputMask = Chr(34) & varMyVariable & Chr(34) & "00000;;*"
```

Will set the input mask to:
"LLL"000000;;*